# How to serve static files(especially images) under protected routes in Chi Router?

Tags: go, go-chi

I am using Chi Router and serving files like this:

```
fileServer := http.FileServer(http.Dir("./static/"))
mux.Handle("/static/*", http.StripPrefix("/static", fileServer))
```

In the html file:

```
<img src="./static/images/img.png" />
```

All's working great and when checking the path of img.png is `http://localhost:8080/static/images/img.png` WHICH is GOOD... BUT when user visit the profile...

```
mux.Route("/user", func(mux chi.Router) {
    mux.Use(Auth)
    mux.Get("/profile", handlers.Repo.ProfileGet) // path: /user/profile
})
```

After the user logs in and visit this path `http://localhost:8080/user/profile` the images do not appear(because the path has been changed)... When I inspected the image path i found: `http://localhost:8080/user/static/images/img.png` instead of `http://localhost:8080/static/images/img.png`

How this issue can be fixed ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Problem is related to the way relative URLs are resolved in HTML

```
<img src="./static/images/img.png" />
```

This path is resolved relative to the current URL in the browser.

To fix this problem use an absolute path for your static resources in your HTML.

```
<img src="/static/images/img.png" />
```

By adding a leading /, you're specifying that the path should be resolved from the root of the domain